# PHP: Encoded + is replaced with space

Tags: php, .htaccess

There are a lot of similar questions here, but I have found none to help me.
Basically, i have a string like this:

```
Collections/Linkin Park/Dead By Sunrise (2009) %2B Album Cover
```

The string is part of a longer url, and this specific part gets assigned to the $_GET array, through a .htaccess RewriteRule. When I echo the string stored in $_GET, I get:

```
Collections/Linkin Park/Dead By Sunrise (2009) Album Cover
```

The %2B just disappears (In the webpage source, it shows three spaces). Why is that? And how can I prevent it?

It's only an error with +. I know php treats + as a space, but it shouldn't when it's encoded.

Comment: @anubhava It actualy shows the value correctly: sub=Entertainment&page=Music&e1=Collections/Linkin Park/Dead By Sunrise (2009) + Album Cover but then I need a way to extract only the part I need.

Comment: @RyanVincent I am currently using rawurlencode, but rawurlencode and urlencode don't make a huge difference.

Comment: @anubhava RewriteRule ^Entertainment/Music/(.*)/$ ?sub=Entertainment&page=Music&e1=$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`B` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) in your rule, that instructs RewriteRule to escape non-alphanumeric characters before applying the transformation:

```
RewriteRule ^Entertainment/Music/(.*)/$ ?sub=Entertainment&page=Music&e1=$1 [B,QSA,NC,L]
```

Now when you dump `$_GET` array you will get:

```
Array
(
    [sub] => Entertainment
    [page] => Music
    [e1] => Collections/Linkin Park/Dead By Sunrise (2009) + Album Cover
)
```

Note appearance of `+` before `Album Cover`.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't really looked into the different flags. I just found some that worked.